# Angular 4 Server-side rendering with Node.js (ReferenceError: document is not defined)

Tags: node.js, angular

I followed the tutorial [here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/55/How-to-Install-an-Angular-4-App) to implement a server-side rendering Angular 4 app. However, I don't know how to solve the problem related to "document is not defined" in Node.js. I know that Node.js doesn't have a DOM since it is not a "browser". However, I seriously need to render the app in server for SEO, yet I don't know how to solve these problem. I can't change the code as it is a third party code, hmmm... any suggestion?

```
/var/www/nodejs/example.com/node_modules/custom-event/index.js:24
'function' === typeof document.createEvent ? function CustomEvent (type, params) {
                  ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodejs/example.com/node_modules/custom-event/index.js:24:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodejs/example.com/node_modules/crossvent/src/crossvent.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
```

I search quite a few posts related to "document is not defined", and most of them just explain that node.js doesn't have a DOM, but without any solution provided.

If you need my `server.ts`, then here is it.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory';
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
const PORT = 4000;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
    const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };
    renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
        .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: i give up "temporarily"... while still waiting for better answer. Some tutorials suggest to remove those third-party scripts which required 'document', 'window', etc and built it especially for the server, while serving the complete app for the client. However, i didn't try this, as temporarily server-rendering function is not my project priority... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs does not support `window, document, navigator` types. So, the solution would be to copy the folder into another directory for example in `src/server-mocks/` and replace all `document` types with `global` in the `index.js` file and configure `webpack.server.config.js` by adding the following code..

```
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');

 new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /crossvent(\\|\/)src(\\|\/)crossvent.js/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src/server-mocks/crossvent/src/crossvent.js')    
    ),
```

Comment: I dont have a webpack.server.config.js . Using Angular 5+ & angular cli 1.5.0

Comment: Angular Universal would be good solution to render your angular app for SEO. You can find the implementation here https://github.com/ng-seed/universal . The following link has a starting example https://github.com/khaled-ansary/universal-starter . At this moment, it is supporting angular 4+ and angular cli 1.3.0.